# Show that $1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2 (n+1)} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$ without using the Basel Problem.

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis

From this [Approximation method for the Basel Problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4827565/approximation-method-for-the-basel-problem), these are equivalent

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} = 1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2 (n+1)}$$

**Question**

There are many [Different ways to prove $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ (the Basel problem)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8337/different-ways-to-prove-sum-k-1-infty-frac1k2-frac-pi26-the-b) but are there similar methods to evaluate this series **without** using the known Basel value $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ to avoid any circular reasoning?

$$1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2 (n+1)} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

If true, the Basel Series follows by using the transitive property of equality

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} = 1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2 (n+1)}$$

and
$$1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2 (n+1)} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

then it follows that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

Comment: This question has no importance because $\frac1{n^2(n+1)}=\frac1{n^2}-\frac1{n(n+1)}$, and the sum of the latter fraction is $-1$. So solving this problem would be similar to solving the Basel problem.